# Why i don't see the Shield around my spaceship?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm using unity version 5.6.1f1 Personal.

I'm trying to use this shader code and csharp script from wiki page:

[Shield](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=Shield)

In the editor i did: Assets > Create > Shader > Standrad Surface Shader
The double click on the created shader opened it in visual studio and added this code:

```
Shader "Custom/NewSurfaceShader" {
    Properties
    {
        _Color("_Color", Color) = (0.0,1.0,0.0,1.0)
        _Inside("_Inside", Range(0.0,2.0)) = 0.0
        _Rim("_Rim", Range(0.0,1.0)) = 1.2
        _Texture("_Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
    _Speed("_Speed", Range(0.5,5.0)) = 0.5
        _Tile("_Tile", Range(1.0,10.0)) = 5.0
        _Strength("_Strength", Range(0.0,5.0)) = 1.5
    }

        SubShader
    {
        Tags
    {
        "Queue" = "Transparent"
        "IgnoreProjector" = "True"
        "RenderType" = "Transparent"

    }


        Cull Back
        ZWrite On
        ZTest LEqual


        CGPROGRAM
#pragma surface surf BlinnPhongEditor alpha vertex:vert
        //#pragma target 3.0


        fixed4 _Color;
    sampler2D _CameraDepthTexture;
    fixed _Inside;
    fixed _Rim;
    sampler2D _Texture;
    fixed _Speed;
    fixed _Tile;
    fixed _Strength;

    struct EditorSurfaceOutput
    {
        half3 Albedo;
        half3 Normal;
        half3 Emission;
        half3 Gloss;
        half Specular;
        half Alpha;
    };

    inline half4 LightingBlinnPhongEditor_PrePass(EditorSurfaceOutput s, half4 light)
    {
        half3 spec = light.a * s.Gloss;

        half4 c;

        c.rgb = (s.Albedo * light.rgb + light.rgb * spec);

        c.a = s.Alpha + Luminance(spec);

        return c;


    }

    inline half4 LightingBlinnPhongEditor(EditorSurfaceOutput s, half3 lightDir, half3 viewDir, half atten)
    {
        viewDir = normalize(viewDir);
        half3 h = normalize(lightDir + viewDir);

        half diff = max(0, dot(s.Normal, lightDir));

        float nh = max(0, dot(s.Normal, h));
        float3 spec = pow(nh, s.Specular*128.0) * s.Gloss;

        half4 res;
        res.rgb = _LightColor0.rgb * (diff * atten * 2.0);
        res.w = spec * Luminance(_LightColor0.rgb);

        return LightingBlinnPhongEditor_PrePass(s, res);
    }

    struct Input
    {
        float4 screenPos;
        float3 viewDir;
        float2 uv_Texture;
    };


    void vert(inout appdata_full v, out Input o)
    {
        UNITY_INITIALIZE_OUTPUT(Input,o);
    }


    void surf(Input IN, inout EditorSurfaceOutput o)
    {
        o.Albedo = fixed3(0.0,0.0,0.0);
        o.Normal = fixed3(0.0,0.0,1.0);
        o.Emission = 0.0;
        o.Gloss = 0.0;
        o.Specular = 0.0;
        o.Alpha = 1.0;
        float4 ScreenDepthDiff0 = LinearEyeDepth(tex2Dproj(_CameraDepthTexture, UNITY_PROJ_COORD(IN.screenPos)).r) - IN.screenPos.z;
        float4 Saturate0 = fixed4(0.3,0.3,0.3,1.0);//
        float4 Fresnel0_1_NoInput = fixed4(0,0,1,1);
        float dNorm = 1.0 - dot(normalize(float4(IN.viewDir, 1.0).xyz), normalize(Fresnel0_1_NoInput.xyz));
        float4 Fresnel0 = float4(dNorm,dNorm,dNorm,dNorm);
        float4 Step0 = step(Fresnel0,float4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0));
        float4 Clamp0 = clamp(Step0,_Inside.xxxx,float4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0));
        float4 Pow0 = pow(Fresnel0,(_Rim).xxxx);
        float4 Multiply5 = _Time * _Speed.xxxx;
        float4 UV_Pan0 = float4((IN.uv_Texture.xyxy).x,(IN.uv_Texture.xyxy).y + Multiply5.x,(IN.uv_Texture.xyxy).z,(IN.uv_Texture.xyxy).w);
        float4 Multiply1 = UV_Pan0 * _Tile.xxxx;
        float4 Tex2D0 = tex2D(_Texture,Multiply1.xy);
        float4 Multiply2 = Tex2D0 * _Strength.xxxx;
        float4 Multiply0 = Pow0 * Multiply2;
        float4 Multiply3 = Clamp0 * Multiply0;
        float4 Multiply4 = Saturate0 * Multiply3;
        o.Emission = Multiply3.xyz * _Color.rgb;
        o.Alpha = Multiply3.w * _Color.a;

    }
    ENDCG
    }
        Fallback "Diffuse"
}
```

Then created a csharp script file:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ShieldUvAnimation : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject iShield;
    public float iSpeed;

    private Material mMaterial;
    private float mTime;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        mMaterial = iShield.GetComponent<Renderer>().material;

        mTime = 0.0f;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        mTime += Time.deltaTime * iSpeed;

        mMaterial.SetFloat("_Offset", Mathf.Repeat(mTime, 1.0f));
    }

}
```

Then i created a material new material and dragged the shader to the material.
Then created a new empty GameObject.

Then attached the csharp script to the new empty GameObject.

Now the first problem i had is that i could not drag the new material to the empty GameObject. So i changed the csharp script i changed the line:

```
private Material mMaterial;
```

To be public

```
public Material mMaterial;
```

And removed the line in the Start:

```
mMaterial = iShield.GetComponent<Renderer>().material;
```

Then i dragged the new material to the public mMaterial.
Last i dragged my spaceship object to the iShield.

I changed the iSpeed to 1.

Running the game i'm not getting any errors or exceptions but i don't see any shield.

[image: Spaceship]

Answer (score 1):

Your shader doesn't have property "_Offset".

Script "ShieldUvAnimation" will work with "ShaderLab - ForceField.shader".

Your link [shield](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=Shield)